# Scan row into nested object

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to map my query results into a nested object. The function which fetches all information without filtering I was able to use the `auto_preload` function. For my second function which should filter out the result this is not possible.

This is the way I filter the results:

```
func GetConstructionSiteSearch(c *gin.Context) {
    db := c.MustGet("db").(*gorm.DB)
    var constructionSites []model.ConstructionSite

    var query Query
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&query); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    dbQuery := db.Debug().Model(&model.ConstructionSite{}).Select("*").
        Joins("JOIN projects ON construction_sites.project_refer = projects.project_id").
        Joins("JOIN addresses ON construction_sites.address_refer = addresses.address_id")

    if query.Counties != nil {
        log.Println("Checking Project Name?")
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where("projects.name = ?", "Höngg")
    }
    if query.ConstructionSiteNames != nil {
        log.Println("Checking SiteName")
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where("addresses.country = ?", "Switzerland")
    }

    rows, err := dbQuery.Rows()

    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var constructionSite model.ConstructionSite
        log.Printf("Row: ", rows)
        db.ScanRows(rows, &constructionSite)
        log.Println("Found one!", constructionSite)
        constructionSites = append(constructionSites, constructionSite)
    }

    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, constructionSites)
    }
}
```

My current issue is that I can not completely scan the row into construction site object. The construction site name gets parsed fine but not the project  and address part.

My models:

```
type ConstructionSite struct {
    ConstructionSiteID uint    `gorm:"primary_key" json:"ConstructionSiteID"`
    Name               string  `json:"Name"`
    Project            Project `gorm:"foreignkey:ProjectRefer" json:"Project"`
    Address            Address `gorm:"foreignkey:AddressRefer" json:"Address"`
    AddressRefer       uint
    ProjectRefer       uint
}

type Address struct {
    AddressID    uint   `gorm:"primary_key" json:"AddressID"`
    Country      string `json:"Country"`
    County       string `json:"County"`
    PostalCode   int    `json:"PostalCode"`
    City         string `json:"City"`
    Street       string `json:"Street"`
    StreetNumber int    `json:"StreetNumber"`
}
```

This is the output of the first log output:

```
Row: %!(EXTRA *sql.Rows=&{0xc00040ec80 0x45a7ca0 0xc000390960 <nil> <nil> {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} false <nil> [1 Construction Site One 1 1 1 ProjectName 1 Switzerland City 6014 City Street 8]})
```

And this is the second output:

```
Found one! {1 Construction Site One {0  [] []} {0   0   0} 1 1}
```

How am I supposed to map the project and address parts into the construction site object?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to express `has one` relationships. It seems like the `foreignkey` tag of a `has one` relationship is supposed to be the key within the owned entity's relation which references the owner entity. It doesn't seem like you are doing this properly. Take a look at the docs on `has one` associations for gorm: http://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html. Specifically take note that the `foreignkey` tag of the `Address` member of a `ConstructionSite` should refer to an attribute of the `Address` struct. This doesn't currently seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure if `ScanRows` works for nested objects. Maybe a `db.ScanRows(rows, &constructionSite.Address)` and `db.ScanRows(rows, &constructionSite.Project)` does the trick?